# Xcode 11 not properly loading header files from search paths

Tags: c++, xcode, libraw

I'm trying to build a command line tool in C++ using Xcode 11.2.1, and I'm getting stuck trying to configure my dependencies. I'm trying to use a library called `libraw`, which I've installed via Homebrew. I see a `libraw` directory in `/usr/local/include` and a `libraw.a/libraw.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib`, and I've added those directories in the header search paths and library search paths in the build settings, but when I try to build my project, I get errors about missing symbols from the linker.

Here's my initial test code (for some RAW processing I want to do).

```
#include "libraw/libraw.h"

int main()
{
        // Let us create an image processor
        LibRaw iProcessor;

        // Open the file and read the metadata
        iProcessor.open_file("tether2073.dng");

        // The metadata are accessible through data fields of the class
        printf("Image size: %d x %d\n",iProcessor.imgdata.sizes.width,iProcessor.imgdata.sizes.height);

        // Let us unpack the image
        iProcessor.unpack();

        // Convert from imgdata.rawdata to imgdata.image:
        iProcessor.raw2image();

        // And let us print its dump; the data are accessible through data fields of the class
        for(int i = 0;i < iProcessor.imgdata.sizes.iwidth *  iProcessor.imgdata.sizes.iheight; i++)
           printf("i=%d R=%d G=%d B=%d G2=%d\n",
                        i,
                        iProcessor.imgdata.image[i][0],
                        iProcessor.imgdata.image[i][1],
                        iProcessor.imgdata.image[i][2],
                        iProcessor.imgdata.image[i][3]
                );

        // Finally, let us free the image processor for work with the next image
        iProcessor.recycle();

        return 0;
}
```

This is the linker invocation:

```
Ld /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Products/Debug/RAWNegativeTool normal x86_64 (in target 'RAWNegativeTool' from project 'RAWNegativeTool')
    cd /Users/<user>/Documents/RAWNegativeTool
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.14 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RAWNegativeTool.build/Debug/RAWNegativeTool.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RAWNegativeTool.LinkFileList -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RAWNegativeTool.build/Debug/RAWNegativeTool.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RAWNegativeTool_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RAWNegativeTool.build/Debug/RAWNegativeTool.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RAWNegativeTool_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAWNegativeTool-fwmiuwmyvyuzmtexigwsxnudegjx/Build/Products/Debug/RAWNegativeTool
```

And here are the errors I get when I build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LibRaw::unpack()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LibRaw::recycle()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LibRaw::open_file(char const*, long long)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LibRaw::raw2image()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LibRaw::LibRaw(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "LibRaw::~LibRaw()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also attempted to add `-l libraw` to the "Other Linker Flags", but I got this error, which indicates that Xcode also can't find my libraries:

`ld: library not found for -llibraw`

My code is taken directly from the `libraw` examples, and those symbols do appear to be defined in `/usr/local/include/libraw/libraw.h` so I'm sort of at a loss.

Comment: you want `-llibraw` not `-l libraw`

Comment: I tried that as well, just added the space in case that was the issue. Same error.